# "nauseous" vs "nauseating" - Differences?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

What are the differences between "nauseous" and "nauseating"? Both words seem to have the same meaning in the dictionaries I have looked at.

[Nauseating](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nauseating):

> making you feel as if you are going to vomit

[Nauseous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nauseous)

> feeling as if you might vomit
>
> making you feel as if you might vomit

Comment: Hot tip, it's always a good idea to include the dictionary definitions in a question that is asking about differences between words. "Seem" is vague, actually *show* the community exactly why it's difficult to tell the two words apart.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Apologies, I hope now it is better. Still a duplicate, but I think now the question was bettered.

Comment: +1 For the edit. You're absolutely right that your question is a duplicate  but it will be more useful for future visitors who happen to read this post first.

Comment: The difference is analogous to that of "furious" and "infuriating". "Nauseating" is something causing a feeling of nausea in someone. "Nauseous" refers to the person so affected.